# .NET any class inherits from Object but cannot access MemberwiseClone() method

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

Trying to write a generic Duplicate extension method, I found that MemberwiseClone() is not accesible.

```
public static T Duplicate<T>(this T original) where T : class
{
    T result = (T) original.MemberwiseClone();

}
```

The compiler rejects the unique line of the method.
Microsoft shows the method in the Object class documentation. Also, in NET any class defined by the programmer inherits implicitly from Object. 
What is going?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this method is protected. https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The compiler doesn't say "rejected", it gives you a very specific error message "Cannot access protected member 'object.MemberwiseClone()' via a qualifier of type 'object'; the qualifier must be of type 'X' (or derived from it)". The "cannot access **protected**" part is the explanation, a protected method is only accessible *inside* the class or a descendant class, not from the outside.

Comment: But if every class inherits from Object, and being the method protected, why cannot access it? Note I´m stating that T must be class, so the inheritance is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

This method is protected, so you can only access it inside class scope.

See:

[image]

[MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
protected object MemberwiseClone()
```

Comment: Excuse me. In my question I stated that the method is protected. But asa said, if every class inherits from Object, I cannot see why the compiler error. And your answer don´t explain my question.

Comment: Sorry @Marcelo, I cant see where you told you know that the method is protected. I think you dont fully understand what protected modifier really does. In C# protected methods are not accessible outside class scope. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
    public static T Duplicate<T>( this T source )
    {
        Type OfT = typeof(T);
        T result = (T) OfT.GetConstructor(System.Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);

        FieldInfo[] objectFields = OfT.GetFields( BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance 
                                                    | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy );

        foreach (FieldInfo fi in objectFields) {
            if (fi.FieldType == typeof(string)) {
                string sourcestring = (string)fi.GetValue(source);
                fi.SetValue(result, new string(sourcestring.ToCharArray()));
            }
            else 
                fi.SetValue(result, fi.GetValue(source));
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Of course, your class must have a parameterless constructor. In my case, I need to duplicate the strings. For a more general case, one could add a boolean argument to control where the strings are duplicated or simply reference the original ones.